# Spring Database connection not getting closed

Tags: java, spring

I am using SPRING `BatchPreparedStatementSetter` object to to do batch insertion of records in 1 table.

Once this is completed it is performing batch update in another table.

This process is repeated for multiple times depending on the number of records.

Now, Issue i am encountering is that after fix no iterations, Database connection is not getting obtained and system is just hanging as Spring is not returning any output.

After analysis its found the system is reaching the maximum permissible limit of connection which is perfectly valid but I have an understanding that Spring framework should take care of connection release process after each CRUD operation.

Is there anyway to handle this connection pooling issues. I am using Apache BasicDataSource as `DataSource` object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share some source code?

Comment: Post the method implementation that does batch insertion using spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by implementing transaction management in code.

Also major issue was that in one of the select clause, connection was not getting closed. Hence by explicitly calling close method on a Connection object, it was getting closed and hence system was not crossing max connection limmit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Code detail is something like this -

    Service class -

public class ServiceImpl {
----
    if (list.size() == 1000) {
           daoInstance.storeRecordsinDB(list);
           daoInstance.updateRecordsInDB(list2);
    }
-----
   }
    Another class DaoInstance -

    public class DaoInstance extends JdbcTemplate {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate =jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void storeRecords(List<dtoObj> valueList) {

           getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(insertSql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {


                     dtoObj dto = valueList.get(i);             
                     ps.setLong(1, dto.getId());
                     ps.setString(2, dto.getName();


                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return valueList.size();                    
                }
            }) ;
    }


    public void updateRecordsInDB(final List<Long> idList)  {


            try {

                getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(updateSQL, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                    @Override
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                                              long id = idList.get(i)
                        ps.setLong(1, id);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        if (idList != null ) {
                            return idList.size();
                        }else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

Implemented transaction management on service class in Spring xml file as -

<tx:advice id = "txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="false"/>
            <!-- <tx:method name="*" read-only="true"/> -->
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.package.serviceImpl.process*(..))" id="accuracyOperation"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="accuracyOperation"/>
    </aop:config>
```

Comment: Why are you posting the code as an answer??? You need to edit your answer with this code.